# Making a list in Google Sheets for json output

Tags: json, csv, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm attempting to use Google Sheets to make an audio library that would translate nicely into json (via CSV or some kind of live feed), but I haven't got clue on how to make sub columns that I'll later on use as tags (genre, lyrics theme etc).

Here's the correct json output I want to get from my spreadsheet:

```
{
    "Songs": [
        {
            "Title": "Bed of Roses",
            "Artist": "Bon Jovi",
            "Metadata": {
                "LyricsTheme": [
                    "Love",
                    "Romantic"
                ],
                "Genre": [
                    "Hard rock",
                    "Ballad"
                ] 
            }
        },
        {
            "Title": "Blue Monday",
            "Artist": "New Order",
            "Metadata": {
                "LyricsTheme": [
                    "A",
                    "B",
                    "C"
                ],
                "Genre": [
                    "Synthpop",
                    "Postpunk",
                    "New wave"
                ] 
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is what I've tried so far with Google Sheets (but that's nowhere near how I want it to be):
[image: Sheets]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you going to use to convert the table into JSON?  If using a Sheets Add-on, best to follow any documentation they provide.  If using Google App Scripts, typically for building an object, you would have one field for each key.  For fields with multiple results, you can comma separate each item, which can be converted into an array in your code.  The hierarchy of the JSON object is set up in the function.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, maybe my title could be misleading - I've used a couple of random csv to json generators online, so my first goal is to make the spreadsheet work for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have all of your field names in the first row, and you create the nesting with slashes like this:

[image]

This will give you:

```
[
 {
   "Title": "Bed of Roses",
   "Artist": "Bon Jovi",
   "Metadata": {
      "LyricsTheme": "Love, Romantic",
      "Genre": "Hard Rock, Ballad"
   }
},
 {
   "Title": "Blue Monday",
   "Artist": "New Order",
   "Metadata": {
      "LyricsTheme": "Dogs, Cats, Birds",
      "Genre": "Synthpop, Postpunk, New wave"
   }
}
]
```

Finally, in the utility that you use to convert the CSV to JSON, You need to find the output setting that gives you a Top Level Property Name, or something similar.

I used [convertcsv.com](https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm) and it is in the output section.

That will give you:

```
{
"Songs": [
 {
   "Title": "Bed of Roses",
   "Artist": "Bon Jovi",
   "Metadata": {
      "LyricsTheme": "Love, Romantic",
      "Genre": "Hard Rock, Ballad"
   }
},
 {
   "Title": "Blue Monday",
   "Artist": "New Order",
   "Metadata": {
      "LyricsTheme": "Dogs, Cats, Birds",
      "Genre": "Synthpop, Postpunk, New wave"
   }
}
]
}
```